# ADC code on atmega2560

Tags: arduino, atmega

I have writing code to measure ADC values on channel numbers stored in ch1 array(first 2 channels correspond to measurement of capacitor voltage Vc; then next 6 channels correspond to measurement of Grid current Ia,Ib,Ic; and last 6 channels correspond to measurement of Grid voltage Va,Vb,Vc ). 
I am writing code for Atmega2560 of arduino-Mega.

Over-all structure of code:
1.In function setup(), i have initialized ADC, Serial-monitor and interrupt
2.In function loop(), i am starting ADC conversion for each channels stored in array named ch1 to get capacitor voltage, grid current and grid voltage in sequence.

I am unable to get desired result,by which i mean that nothing is printed on Serial terminal after 5-6 lines.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
//#include <util/atomic.h>


#define ChannelMax 4
uint8_t ch1[]={0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6};//channels for //Vc,Vc,Ia,Ia,Ib,IB,Ic,Ic,Va,Va,Vb,Vb,Vc,Vc(capacitor voltage,grid current,grid voltage)

volatile unsigned short ci=0;//index for ch1 array

unsigned int ADarray[15];//array to store ADC output data
volatile unsigned short readFlag=0;//it is set from ADC ISR when either Vc 
or all I or all V is measured twice     






void setupADC();
uint16_t adc_read(uint8_t ch);
void adc_start(uint8_t ch);
//setup function detail for arduino
void setup()
{
   cli();

   Serial.begin(9600);        // connect to the serial port
   setupADC();

   sei();


}

//looping for infinity
void loop()
{
   while(1) 
   {

    //initialize things
    ci=0;// start with first channel present in ch1
    Serial.print("Vc measuring started with");
    Serial.println(ch1[ci]);
    adc_start(ch1[ci]);//start adc to measure Vc i.e ch1[0] and ch1[1]
    //do something whil Vc is measured

   while(1){ //wait till end of ADC measurement of Vc
     if(readFlag==0){
     Serial.println(readFlag);
     Serial.println("Vc beingmeasured"); 
   }
   else break;

  };
  readFlag=0; Serial.println("Vc finally measured"); 
 //use Vc i.e. ADarray[1] for calculation



 Serial.print("I measuring started with ");Serial.println(ch1[ci]);
 adc_start(ch1[ci]);//start adc to measure grid current Ia,Ib,Ic i.e ch1[2] 
   //to ch1[7]
 //do something while grid current is being measured
 while(1){  //wait for end of measurement of grid current
  if(readFlag==0){
    Serial.println(readFlag);
    Serial.println("I beingmeasured"); 
  }
  else break;
 };
readFlag=0; Serial.println("I finally measured"); 
//Use i i.e. ADarray[3],5,7 for calculation





 Serial.print("V measuring started with ");Serial.println(ch1[ci]);
  adc_start(ch1[ci]);//start measurement of grid voltage Va,Vb and Vc
 //do something while grid volt is being measured
 while(1){//wait till end of measurement of grid voltage
   if(readFlag==0){
    Serial.println(readFlag);
    Serial.println("V beingmeasured"); 
   }
   else break;
 };
 readFlag=0;Serial.println("V finally measured"); 
 //Use V i.e. ADarray[9],11,13 for calculation




  }//end of while loop
}//end of loop function

 //setup registers for ADC in atmega 2560
 void setupADC(){
   ADCSRA = 0;
    ADCSRB = 0;
    ADMUX = ch1[ci];        // Channel 0 only
    ADMUX |= (1<<REFS0);//ADMUX|=0b01000000;//use it if u want to use AVCC       //as Aref internally ,but dont forget to use external cap at AREF

    ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)  ;  // Enable ADC, 
    //ADCSRA |= _BV(ADPS2) | _BV(ADPS1) | _BV(ADPS0) ;//prescale at 128.
    ADCSRA|=_BV(ADIE);//to interupt enable for ADC 
    //ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC);  // Start initial ADC cycle


}   
//Interrupt service routine for ADC measurment
ISR(ADC_vect){

    ADarray[ci]=(unsigned int)ADC;
    Serial.print(ch1[ci]);Serial.println("adc read");
    ci++;ci++;Serial.print(ci);
    //if(ci>=ChannelMax) ci=0;

    if((ci==2) ||( ci==8) ||(ci==14)){
     Serial.println("finished");
     readFlag=1;
     return ;
    }   
   //Serial.println("adc started");
   adc_start(ch1[ci]);
   //Serial.print(ch1[ci]);Serial.println("adc started");





}



//function to start ADC for particular channel
void adc_start(uint8_t ch){
     // Serial.print(ch);Serial.println("adc started subroutine");
    // select the corresponding channel 0~7
    // ANDing with ’7? will always keep the value
    // of ‘ch’ between 0 and 7
    ch &= 0b00001111;  // AND operation with 7
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xF0)|ch; // clears the bottom 3 bits before ORing

    // start single convertion
    // write ’1? to ADSC
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing things, i understood that One shouldn't use Serial.print inside ISR or any function called from ISR(perhaps because Serial.print uses interrupt)... Then question is that how to debug inside ISR? Can i use Atomic_Block to do something?